# why Eclipse not starting without showing any error?

Tags: eclipse

When I try to start eclipse it is not starting and it isn't show any error.Just came the start up screen and then vanish.What is the reason of that.?

Comment: You should give us more info, like your operating system, eclipse version, any command line output etc.

Comment: Look in the file .metadata/.log inside your workspace; you'll probably see whatever errors caused the crash recorded there.

Comment: i am using windows 8 & eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32 @Ernest Friedman-Hill there is nothin in log too.

Comment: You can use a terminal to start the application. just open a terminal and go to the eclipse location( cd.... :)  ). Then execute the command ./eclipse. Then you will find the eclipse log. This log may be helpful you to understand what is going on under the cover :P